# Does std::reverse_iterator work with adapted ranges?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I remember having read that the motivation for [[forward.iterators]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/forward.iterators#6) (requiring that, given two iterators `a` and `b`, `a == b` if and only if `*a` and `*b` are bound to the same object) was to support `reverse_iterator`s. Am I remembering correctly?

[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) notes that

> For a reverse iterator `r` constructed from an iterator `i`, the relationship `&*r == &*(i-1)` is always `true` (as long as `r` is dereferenceable); thus a reverse iterator constructed from a one-past-the-end iterator dereferences to the last element in a sequence.

and also:

> `std::reverse_iterator` does not work with iterators whose dereference returns a reference to a member of `*this` (so-called "stashing iterators"). An example of a stashing iterator is `std::filesystem::path::iterator`.

However, it is also stated that:

> `std::reverse_iterator` is an iterator adaptor that reverses the direction of a given iterator, which must be at least a `LegacyBidirectionalIterator` or model `bidirectional_iterator` (since C++20).

which is exactly what the standard [says](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterators#reverse.iter.requirements-1).

If I’m not mistaken, C++20 `bidirectional_iterator`s no longer require [forward.iterators]/6. For example, `std::ranges::iota_view::iterator` is a `std::random_access_iterator` but also a stashing iterator. Therefore, I don’t understand why `std::bidirectional_iterator` is a sufficient requirement for `std::reverse_iterator` to work if the above claim about stashing iterators is true.

Indeed, the following program displays the expected output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
  auto v = std::views::iota(0u, 10'000ul) | std::views::take(10);

  for (auto it = std::make_reverse_iterator(v.end());
       it != std::make_reverse_iterator(v.begin()); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

There isn’t really much point in using `std::reverse_iterator` with C++20 iterators, since we have `std::ranges::reverse_view`, but I’m curious to know whether [forward.iterators]/6 is currently necessary at all.

Comment: *"If I’m not mistaken, C++20 bidirectional_iterators no longer require [forward.iterators]/6."* - The link you mentioned says the opposite: both the `bidirectional_­iterator` and the *Cpp17BidirectionalIterator* extend forward iterator concepts.

Comment: Why is `iota_view::iterator` a stashing iterator?

Comment: @Holt See the note at the end of this page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/forward_iterator

Comment: @康桓瑋 because it doesn't return a reference to an element in the range but a copy of an integer stored in the iterator itself.

Comment: @metalfox. "*std::reverse_iterator does not work with iterators whose dereference returns a reference to a member of *this (so-called "stashing iterators").*" But what `iota_view::iterator` returns is *not* a reference but a prvalue, so it is not satisfied the definition of stashing iterators from the beginning, is it? Or is there something I missed?

Comment: @康桓瑋 It needs not to be a reference. Stashing iterators cache the thing being iterated within themselves.

Comment: Is "whose dereference returns a reference" not clear enough to you? I'm happy to change cppreference if you think it suggest that the dereference can return a copy.

Comment: @cpplearner That's clear. It was *"the relationship `&*r == &*(i-1)` is always `true`"* what confused me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The note about stashing iterators is not about l-value vs r-value return from `*`, but instead about the multi-pass guarantee.

`std::forward_iterator` still has the semantic requirement "`((void)[](auto x){ ++x; }(i), *i)` is equivalent to `*i`", which *is* met by `decltype(v.begin())`, but is not (required to be) met by `std::filesystem::path::`(`const_`)`iterator`.

> `const_iterator` a constant *LegacyBidirectionalIterator* with a `value_type` of path, except that for dereferenceable iterators `a` and `b` of type `path::iterator` with `a == b`, there is no requirement that `*a` and `*b` are bound to the same object

N.b. `std::reverse_view` is (for some expressions) defined to return a `ranges::subrange<reverse_iterator<...>>`, so it is still relevant.

Comment: So, is the statement *"the relationship `&*r == &*(i-1)` is always true"* out of date? I believe there was similar wording in the standard but I couldn't find it in the current draft.

Comment: @metalfox in the sense that `*i` (and thus `*r`) are permitted to be rvalues, so that expression might be ill-formed, yes